# In SQLplus, is there a way to execute a file by using an environment variable?

Tags: sqlplus

I am using sqlplus on a windows environment. At the moment i run sqlplus from a specific directory. I have several scripts that are in several places on my machine. Here are example commands i use within sqlplus to execute some of these scripts.

```
sqlplus> @../../scripts/oracle/viewdbajobs.sql
sqlplus> @../../../../../devhome/admin/scripts/listinactiveusers.sql
sqlplus> @../../../../../../../web/app/testscript.sql
```

its quite annoying to have to type all that just to access a directory. I am thinking if i can configure several environment variable for each location i can then do something like this

```
sqlplus> @$ORACLE_SCRIPTS/viewdbajobs.sql
sqlplus> @$DEVHOME_SCRIPTS/listinactiveusers.sql
sqlplus> @$WEB_HOME/testscripts.sql
```

Is the above possible? If not, is there a better alternative approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok ive found out that this actually works.

```
sqlplus @%DEV_HOME%/test.sql
```

Thanks